# Need advice with two properties constraints

Tags: grails

I need your help in this scenario.
I have the following domain class:

```
class Payment {
    BigDecimal cash
    BigDecimal checkValue

    static constraints = {
        cash nullable: true
        checkValue nullable: true
    }
}
```

The `cash` and `checkValue` properties are nullable, but at least one of them has to have a value.

I hope I was able to explain my problem.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Custom validator seems to be a good option in this case. Try with:

```
class Payment {
    BigDecimal cash
    BigDecimal checkValue

    static constraints = {
        cash nullable: true, validator: { val, obj -> 
            val != null || obj.checkValue != null 
        }
        checkValue nullable: true, validator: { val, obj -> 
            val != null || obj.cash != null 
        }
    }
}
```

With [groovy truth](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Truth) you can simplify the validator closures to something like below:

```
static constraints = {
        cash nullable: true, validator: { val, obj -> val || obj.checkValue }
        checkValue nullable: true, validator: { val, obj -> val || obj.cash }
}
```

For more information take a look at [Validation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html) section of grails documentation.